# Fastest way to select min row with join

Tags: mysql, sql

In this example, I have a listing of users (main_data), a pass list (pass_list) and a corresponding priority to each pass code type (pass_code). The query I am constructing is looking for a list of users and the corresponding pass code type with the lowest priority. The query below works but it just seems like there may be a faster way to construct it I am missing. SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2ec8d/2/0 or see below for table details.

```
SELECT md.first_name, md.last_name, pl.* 
FROM main_data md
JOIN pass_list pl on pl.main_data_id = md.id 
AND
pl.id = 
  (
    SELECT pl2.id 
    FROM pass_list pl2 
    JOIN pass_code pc2 on pl2.pass_code_type = pc2.type 
    WHERE pl2.main_data_id = md.id 
    ORDER BY pc2.priority 
    LIMIT 1
  )
```

Results:

```
+------------+-----------+----+--------------+----------------+
| first_name | last_name | id | main_data_id | pass_code_type |
+------------+-----------+----+--------------+----------------+
| Bob        | Smith     |  1 |            1 | S              |
| Mary       | Vance     |  8 |            2 | M              |
| Margret    | Cough     |  5 |            3 | H              |
| Mark       | Johnson   |  9 |            4 | H              |
| Tim        | Allen     | 13 |            5 | M              |
+------------+-----------+----+--------------+----------------+
```

users (main_data)

```
+----+------------+-----------+
| id | first_name | last_name |
+----+------------+-----------+
|  1 | Bob        | Smith     |
|  2 | Mary       | Vance     |
|  3 | Margret    | Cough     |
|  4 | Mark       | Johnson   |
|  5 | Tim        | Allen     |
+----+------------+-----------+
```

pass list (pass_list)

```
+----+--------------+----------------+
| id | main_data_id | pass_code_type |
+----+--------------+----------------+
|  1 |            1 | S              |
|  3 |            2 | E              |
|  4 |            2 | H              |
|  5 |            3 | H              |
|  7 |            4 | E              |
|  8 |            2 | M              |
|  9 |            4 | H              |
| 10 |            4 | H              |
| 11 |            5 | S              |
| 12 |            3 | S              |
| 13 |            5 | M              |
| 14 |            1 | E              |
+----+--------------+----------------+
```

Table which specifies priority (pass_code)

```
+----+------+----------+
| id | type | priority |
+----+------+----------+
|  1 | M    |        1 |
|  2 | H    |        2 |
|  3 | S    |        3 |
|  4 | E    |        4 |
+----+------+----------+
```

Answer (score 1):

Due to mysql's unique extension to its GROUP BY, it's simple:

```
SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT md.first_name, md.last_name, pl.* 
FROM main_data md
JOIN pass_list pl on pl.main_data_id = md.id
ORDER BY pc2.priority) x
GROUP BY md.id
```

This returns only the first row encountered for each unique value of `md.id`, so by using an inner query to order the rows before applying the group by you get only the rows you want.

Comment: While it normally does work, which rows values it brings back is officially undefined. So in future it might not be the first row.

Comment: @Kickstart yes... people keep saying that, but it's worked for years and years like that, and if it ever changes I'll worry about that then. Until then, I personally think it's fine to utilize this incredibly convenient "feature".

Comment: Fair point, but if it does change I expect it to be a nightmare to find which queries have had what problems.

Comment: @Kickstart but of course we all have unit tests for all our queries and they would fail and immediately highlight which queries need work. [We do have unit tests... don't we???](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fh1_jiKfzLw) :)

Comment: lol . Even finding some of the old queries (some of which are truely awful) is a nightmare around here. Even if found by unit tests, going through thousands of queries to correct them doesn't appeal.

Comment: Even taking out the issue of MySQL possibly changing results in the future, this query takes 3 - 4 seconds on a large data set compared with 0.0035 - 0.0043 from my query above. This uses 2 temporary; using filesort and using where; using join buffer. My original uses filesort once with no temporary. I had to modify the query to this for it to even work: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2ec8d/7/0

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the special behavior of MySQL's group by, but my solution for these types of problems is to simply express as where there doesn't exist a row with a lower priority.  This is standard SQL so should work on any DB.

```
select distinct u.id, u.first_name, u.last_name, pl.pass_code_type, pc.id, pc.priority 
from main_data u 
  inner join pass_list pl on pl.main_data_id = u.id
  inner join pass_code pc on pc.type = pl.pass_code_type
where not exists (select 1 
                  from pass_list pl2 
                    inner join pass_code pc2 on pc2.type = pl2.pass_code_type 
                  where pl2.main_data_id = u.id and pc2.priority < pc.priority);
```

How well this performs is going to depend on having the proper indexes (assuming that main_data and pass_list are somewhat large). In this case indexes on the primary (should be automatically created) and foreign keys should be sufficient.  There may be other queries that are faster, I would start by comparing this to your query.

Also, I had to add distinct because you have duplicate rows in pass_list (id 9 & 10), but if you ensure that duplicates can't exist (unique index on main_data_id, pass_code_type) then you will save some time by removing the distinct which forces a final sort of the result set.  This savings would be more noticeable the larger the result set is.

Comment: This query produces duplicates for user Mark Johnson. Also, there must be duplicate rows in pass_list and the query will pick one with the highest priority and display that one.

Comment: @John  You're right.  I have removed the column pl.id from the select list and that should fix the duplicate problem and make my earlier comments regarding "select distinct" vs "select" valid.

Comment: @John When you say there must be duplicates in pass_list you mean there must be exact duplicates, as in pl.id 9 & 10, or just that there are more than one pass_list row that joins a given main_data with a given pass_code?

Comment: Sorry I should have been clearer. I meant to say there may be duplicates and that should not affect the results.  id 9 & 10 are correct and going forward there could be similar duplicates

Answer (score 0):

A version that will get the details as required, and should also work across different flavours of SQL

```
SELECT md.first_name, md.last_name, MinId, pl.main_data_id, pl.pass_code_type
FROM main_data md
INNER JOIN pass_list pl
ON md.id = pl.main_data_id
INNER JOIN pass_code pc
ON pl.pass_code_type = pc.type
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT pl.main_data_id, pl.pass_code_type, Sub0.MinPriority, MIN(pl.id) AS MinId
    FROM pass_list pl
    INNER JOIN pass_code pc
    ON pl.pass_code_type = pc.type
    INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT main_data_id, MIN(priority) AS MinPriority
        FROM pass_list a
        INNER JOIN pass_code b
        ON a.pass_code_type = b.type
        GROUP BY main_data_id
    ) Sub0
    ON pl.main_data_id = Sub0.main_data_id
    AND pc.priority = Sub0.MinPriority
    GROUP BY pl.main_data_id, pl.pass_code_type, Sub0.MinPriority
) Sub1
ON pl.main_data_id = Sub1.main_data_id
AND pl.id = Sub1.MinId
AND pc.priority = Sub1.MinPriority
ORDER BY pl.main_data_id
```

This does not rely on the flexibility of MySQLs GROUP BY functionality.

Comment: This works but seems awfully complicated and is still slower than my original query. What would be the benefits of this over the one I posted? This one takes 5 - 6 seconds with a large data set compared to less than a second on my original query. This also uses temporary; Using filesort 3 times and join buffer twice.

Comment: With a large amount of data, you query should slow down progressively more (in effect it is having to do a separate query for every row), plus as it stands if you query has multiple ids with the same priority it is not defined which one will be returned. However you probably do need some more keys adding (eg, one on type on the pass_code table)